# How to fire change event in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a UserControl placed in aspx page in asp.net. In this UserControl, I have a RadioButtonList and on change of RadioButtonList item, I want to execute the below jQuery function.

```
$('#rdlUser').change(function (e) {
    alert("change function");
    var radioBtnId = this.id;
    var $this = $(this);
    radconfirm('Are you sure you want to take leave?', function(arg){
        if (arg == true) {
            alert("User wants to take leave");
        }    
        else {
            alert("User doesn't want to take leave");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: _I want to execute the below jQuery function._ __When__?

Comment: On selection of one of the items in RadioButtonList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For execute an event you can use `trigger("eventname")` function with JQuery.

**Example**

```js
$("#id").keypress(function(){
  console.log("input keypress");
});

$("#btn").click(function(){
  $("#id").trigger("keypress");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="id"> <button id="btn">Trigger keypress event</button>
```

**UPDATE**

With generated HTML you can't trigger event by using `$("#generatedid")` because element is not in the DOM at the first load.

You can use :

```
$(document).on("change",".your-radio-button-class",function(){
    //Make a test on the value of the select radio
    if($(this).val() == "connected")
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
});
```

Comment: I am populating RadioButtonList items from database and I get 4 list items in RadioButtonList. How can I fire change event for a particular item.

Comment: It's totally different lol. Add some class on your radio. I'll update my answer

Comment: 1. There is no class for my RadioButtonList 2.`alert($this.val())` is returning an empty string 3. `alert($this.val())` is firing 4 times i.e., for each RadioButtonList item

Comment: So create a class on your radio if you want to create an event on them. Or create your event on all `input type radio`

Comment: After adding class, the `$(document).on..` is not throwing the simple alert message. Am I missing something?

Comment: I am using `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js">` and still `on` is not working at all and I am using 1.3.1 version of jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#rdlUser input').change(function () {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```